# how to find accuracy using multiple value of k in knn classifier (matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, pattern-recognition, knn

I use knn classifier to classify images according to their writers (problem of writer recognition). I worked on a given database that contains 150 images with 100 images for training and 50 images for testing. 
I use this code to find the accuracy of the classifier( k=1):

```
load('testdirection.mat') 
load('traindirection.mat')
load('testlabels.mat') 
load('trainlabels.mat') 
class = knnclassify(testdirection,traindirection, trainlabels);
cp = classperf(testlabels,class);
cp.CorrectRate 
fprintf('KNN Classifier Accuracy: %.2f%%\n',100*cp.CorrectRate )
```

I want to find different accuracy for different value for k [1..25] and save result in matrix matlab. I want also to plot the result to see the  variability of accuracy depending on the value of k.
 Please, help me to change this code and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knnclassify` has an optional fourth argument `k` which is the number of nearest neighbors. You can just put the `knnclassify` in a for loop and iterate through all values for `k`.

```
load('testdirection.mat') 
load('traindirection.mat')
load('testlabels.mat') 
load('trainlabels.mat') 

for k=25:-1:1
    class = knnclassify(testdirection,traindirection, trainlabels, k);
    cp = classperf(testlabels,class);
    correctRate(k) = cp.CorrectRate;
end
```

You can plot the result e.g. using `stem` or `plot`

```
stem(1:25,correctRate);
```

PS: note that according to the MATLAB documentation, `knnclassify` will be removed in a future release and you should better use `fitcknn`.

Comment: thanks for your response but I got error wen plot the result : Error using stem (line 44)
X must be same length as Y.

Error in knn1 (line 11)
stem(1:25,k);

Comment: Oh sorry I made a mistake in my anwer. See the edited `stem` statement